# while(i--) loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I normally use while loop as:

```
while (i<some_value)
```

I saw **while(i--)** syntax and thought it is shorter and cooler and tried the following in google-chrome.

```
var num_arr= [4,8,7,1,3];


var length_of_num_arr=num_arr.length;


while(length_of_num_arr--) console.log(num_arr);
 [4, 8, 7, 1, 3]
 [4, 8, 7, 1, 3]
 [4, 8, 7, 1, 3]
 [4, 8, 7, 1, 3]
 [4, 8, 7, 1, 3] **// THIS IS EXPECTED RESULT**
```

But When I try...

```
while((num_arr.length)--) console.log(num_arr);
[4, 8, 7, 1]
[4, 8, 7]
[4, 8]
[4]
[] // WHY IS THIS HAPPENING??
```

Is there some hidden things you need to understand to use this syntax?

Comment: `num_arr.length--` is the same as `num_arr.length = num_arr.length - 1`. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Never thought array length was writable! Thanks

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: Although, if it wasn’t, this still wouldn’t work – the trick depends on `length_of_num_arr` being decremented, after all.

Comment: @minitech: yes you are right....my brain working bad.... Thanks to all of you guys...

Answer (score 8):

Arrays’ `length` property is writable, and will cut off their elements or add empty slots as appropriate when you set it.

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
items.length = 3; // items is now [1, 2, 3]
items.length = 6; // items is now a sparse array: [1, 2, 3, undefined × 3]
```

So, don’t do that.

Comment: Wow!....One thing I knew today at 10:28 PM ..Javascript you never fail to surprise me..

Comment: Is it one of the thing that only happens in javascript? I don't think you can change the length of array this way in any other languages....I don't remember at least in python....

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades: There’s probably something else out there, but I’m not aware of a writable `length` property in any other common languages,  no. VB.NET has `ReDim`, Python has `del arr[-5:]`, etc. as far as unusual slightly unusual possible resizing methods go.

Comment: Note setting `length` to a higher value does not append `undefined`s.

Comment: That should be: `items.length = 6; // items is now a sparse array: [1, 2, 3,,,,];`. The additional elements aren't undefined, they don't exist (i.e. they are not defined, rather than exist and have the value *undefined*).

Comment: @RobG: Right, but I thought that would be confusing, and a lighter `undefined × n` is how the Chrome developer tools show sparse arrays, too.

Comment: There were some dev tools that showed them elided, however they all seem to use *undefined* now. :-(

Answer (score 2):

When you do `array.length--` you're potentially **shortening the array by one element each time**.

See the reference under the section **Shortening the array** from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

`Array.prototype.length` can be re-written programmatically and it potentially shorten your array by the new length you assign.

**For example**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// Shorten the array by one element
a.length--; // a <-- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

// In case you want to shorten your array to 3 elements, you can:
a.length = 3; // a <-- [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `length` property of an array to a lower value, the items at the end are removed:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
arr.length; // 5
arr.length = 3;
arr; // [1,2,3]
```

This is described in the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.1):

> While *newLen* < *oldLen* repeat,
>
> 1. Set *oldLen* to *oldLen* – 1.
> 2. Let *deleteSucceeded* be the result of calling the [[Delete]] internal method of *A* passing [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*oldLen*) and **false**
>      as arguments.

In your code you use the [postfix decrement operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3.2) (`--`) which reduces the `length` of the array.